# How do I inject an Actor with constructor parameters in a Play controller?

Tags: java, playframework, akka

I'm trying to follow the [JavaWebSocket Tutorial on the official docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaWebSockets#handling-websockets-with-actors).

There is this actor:

```
import akka.actor.*;

public class MyWebSocketActor extends UntypedActor {

    public static Props props(ActorRef out) {
        return Props.create(MyWebSocketActor.class, out);
    }

    private final ActorRef out;

    public MyWebSocketActor(ActorRef out) {
        this.out = out;
    }

    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        if (message instanceof String) {
            out.tell("I received your message: " + message, self());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the websocket:

```
public static LegacyWebSocket<String> socket() {
    return WebSocket.withActor(MyWebSocketActor::props);
}
```

This is my controller:

```
@Singleton
public class MessagesController extends BaseController implements CurrentUser {

    private UserProvider userProvider;
    private ActorSystem actorSystem;
    private Materializer materializer;
    private Configuration configuration;
    ActorRef websocketactor;


    @Inject
    public MessagesController(final UserProvider userProvider,
                              ActorSystem actorSystem,
                              Materializer materializer,
                              Configuration configuration

    ) {
        this.userProvider = userProvider;
        this.actorSystem = actorSystem;
        this.materializer = materializer;
        this.configuration = configuration;
        this.websocketactor = actorSystem.actorOf(); // What goes in here ? 

    }
```

Later on after the init process, I'd like to send messages to the actor from controller methods.

```
 this.websocketactor = actorSystem.actorOf(MyWebSocketActor.props()); // this line is giving me errors because I don't know what goes in there.
```

It's probably the **ActorRef out**, which is my websocket, but how do I specify that ?

Comment: Which play version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just answered the same question in another post, but just in case here is it:

You can use lambda for this, here is a quick example:

```
  public LegacyWebSocket<String> socket(String token) {
        return WebSocket.withActor(actorRef -> WSActor.props(actorRef,token));
  }
```

Comment: If the same answer works in multiple post, then the questions are likely duplicates.  It is best if you flag one of the as such...